# Web Application Server

Tags: host

I'm very new to web development but I will try to explain my question as best I can.

I am making a basic chatroom program (in C#) but I have never made my own online server before, and it needs to respond to tcp packets. I know how a server works, I just don't know how to implement my server and how people will be able to access it.

Hope thats clear. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry I didn't mean to ask for examples of chat/server applications, I already know how they work. My question is how do i host an online server that is accessible to anyone?Are they written in php? asp?I dont want to be running an application on my computer that will be the "server". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- If you like to study some existing network applications, i recommend the [twisted project](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedProject); it contains a web server, numerous chat clients, chat servers, mail servers, and more.
- Some example C# code for a chat client and server: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3574/a-chat-clientserver-program-for-c/

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Web Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/).

They have a chat application sample, and it's basically a light, non-blocking web server.  It is written in python.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using c# then you can have a look on signal R as well. It is getting popular because of event based pull / push mechanism which may assist you in the development of chat room.